# Key Down Event increases currentIndex of QCombobox

Tags: python, events, keypress, qcombobox, eventfilter

I am struggling with another curiosity: my QComboBox should loose focus in this momement, the current Index changed. No big deal (I thought) until I pushed the down-key instead of TAB/Return. The current index then will be increased by 1! I ask me really why, but need a solution for that behaviour as well :)

So I added an event filter and tried to detect it there:

```
self.ui.CMB_fett.installEventFilter(self)
...
def eventFilter(self, source, event):
    if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress:
        if source == self.ui.CMB_fett:
            if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Down:
                source.currentIndexChanged.disconnect(self.changed_index)
                source.setCurrentIndex(source.currentIndex()-1)
                source.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.changed_index)    
    return super().eventFilter(source,event)
```

Is this really the correct way or the best practise? My bones tell me, that this is really error-prone and nooby ^^

Comment: maybe show code which makes problem with `QComboBox` - maybe you have mistake in this code.

Comment: few lines before I set up the Box: 
`self.ui.CMB_fett = QtWidgets.QComboBox()`

Comment: better show it in question - and show more code so we could see other elements. It could be better if you create `minimal working code` so we could simply copy and test it. In question you could also add information what system you use because maybe this problem exists only on some systems.